# Git fetch & pull from Visual Studio 2017 not getting the latest commit

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2017, github-for-windows

The latest commit that was made to GIT is not reflecting in a different computer.

In github web, its showing the commits and the change history

[image: Changes reflecting in GitHub browser]
[image: See PatternOne in the middle]
[image: In visual Studio 2017, its not reflecting]
[image: Sync, Fetch & Pull doesn't show the last commit]

Help to get it resolved in Visual Studio pls.

Comment: Try set git.autofetch to true in File / Preferences / Settings / User Settings / Extensions / Git / Autofetch.

Comment: Resolved, I found the latest commit is pulled but it was not displaying in visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, I found the latest commit is pulled but it was not displaying in visual studio

Comment: Did you ever figure out why it was not displaying in Visual Studio?